# How to automated VMWare Workstation backup?

Tags: backup, vmware-esx, automation

I run **VMWare Workstation 6.5** on WinXP.

How can I script a way to automatically clone my VM images?

I've read about the "v`mware-cmd`" tool but believe that is only available with VMWare **ESX**, not **Workstation**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this blog post, might be able to help you:

http://daveclarkesblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/backing-up-vmware-workstation-vms.html

Answer (score 0):

You want the "vmrun" command. It should do pretty much everything vmware-cmd did.